# How to get the :selected form <option> when using .on()?

Tags: jquery

I have a  field that is brought in via an AJAX call:

```
<select id="selection">
    <option value="foo">bar</option>
    <option value="baz">bat</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to use `.on()` to pass the selected element to a function when the field is changed:

```
$(document).on("change", "#selection", function(){ doStuff(jQuery(this).filter("option:selected")); });

function doStuff(selection)
{
    alert(selection.text());
}
```

When the element changes, I only receive a blank alert dialogue. Placing a breakpoint on `alert(selection.text()` gives me:

```
selection: e.fn.e.init[0]
    context: HTMLSelectElement
        0: HTMLOptionElement
        1: HTMLOptionElement
    length: 0
    prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1]
    selector: ".filter(option:selected)"
    __proto__: Object[0]
```

And one of the `HTMLOptionElements` will have a selected: true value. I just don't know how to get the text (bar or bat in my example) from the selected element, using `.on()`.

I would normally do `$('#selection option:selected').text();`, but .on() is playing all sorts of games on me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoa, there.. Why not

```
$(function() {
  $('#selection').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).children(':selected').text());
  });
});
```

Comment: `.children(':selected').text()` worked perfectly. `doStuff()` was just for example, as the real function is reused in other places, thus the anonymous function calls it.

Comment: @Nick Gotcha, makes more sense now

Answer (score 2):

No need to do anything that complex - you can do it in straight JavaScript:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
```

Comment: Unless he wants to manipulate the text and not the value as implied by `$('#selection option:selected').text();`

Comment: @KyleMacey - a bit too quick on the trigger there.  I've updated it; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

.filter is used to produce a result sub-set from the first set, but the first set does not include the options since $(this) refers to the select that was changed.

You need to use .children or .find inside of the change handler to find the :selected option.